# Docker Desktop user must be added to "docker-users" group but I can't change groups in Windows Home

Tags: windows-10, docker-for-windows

Docker Desktop install on Windows Home.
I get the error notification "You must in the docker-users group."

So you can go to compmgmt.msc to add yourself to the group,
but Windows Home doesnt have User Groups management like Windows Pro.

How can I do this for Windows Home?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I do this for Windows Home?

Run the following command in an elevated command prompt.

> `net localgroup docker-users username /add`

Source: [Docker User Group](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/troubleshooting-docker-errors?view=vs-2019#docker-users-group)

You can also run a PowerShell command within an elevated PowerShell prompt:

> `Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "docker-users" -Member "User"`

Comment: There is also a third-party application that could be used [here](https://github.com/proviq/lusrmgr).  However, I offer no warranty on the use of that application, only point out that it exists.